Implementation of below in Redshift from bigquery
Tried with listagg() but result as below:
1 a,b,c
1 a,b,c
1 a,b,c
2 MMM

Need similar implementation as in image bigquery:
with data 1 as (
select
  1 sk,
  'a' st,
  timestamp('1900-05-08 04:00:00') dt
union all
select
  1 sk,
  'b',
  timestamp('1901-05-08 04:00:00')
union all
select
  1 sk,
  'c',
  timestamp('1902-05-08 04:00:00')
union all
select
  2 sk,
  'MMM',
  timestamp('1902-05-08 04:00:00')
)

select
  sk,
    string_agg(st, ',') over (partition by sk order by dt)
from data1

Output:
sk  f0_
 1  a
 1  a,b
 1  a,b,c
 2  MMM

Looking for above mentioned by where concatenated values differ from running total

Do we have any function in REDSHIFT to generate data like in image above to generate data as string_agg (bigquery)

As you have likely read Redshift's listagg() window function doesn't support a frame clause.  However we can emulate this by a detour into SUPER data type.
The code below creates your test data, performs a listagg(), converts these strings to super array, and captures the order of the string within the partition with a row_number() window.  Redshift has a subarray() function that allows for the selection of only portions of the super array.  Remove the brackets and quotes and the desired result is produced.
with data as (
select
  1 sk,
  'a' st,
  '1900-05-08 04:00:00'::timestamp dt
union all
select
  1 sk,
  'b',
  '1901-05-08 04:00:00'::timestamp
union all
select
  1 sk,
  'c',
  '1902-05-08 04:00:00'::timestamp
union all
select
  2 sk,
  'MMM',
  '1902-05-08 04:00:00'::timestamp
),
arrayed as (
select sk, 
  json_parse('["'||listagg(st, '","') within group (order by dt) over (PARTITION by sk)||'"]') as arr,
  row_number() over (partition by sk order by dt)::int as rn
from data
)
select sk, translate(json_serialize(subarray(arr,0,rn)),'[]"','') as foo
from arrayed
order by sk, rn;

